# Web Analytics Services - Do you have any experience with Piwik?

Tags: open-source, analytics, evaluation, piwik

As the question suggests, I'm looking at installing [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) to monitor my sites.  Currently I'm using Clicky, which works well but I'm reluctant to upgrade to the paid version.

Does anyone have any experience or advice about this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piwik is a good stat tool. It isn't as beautiful as GAnalytics, but does its job well.

One thing to note: if you're using it on a high-traffic website, it's better to setup a separate instance to server piwik files.

Comment: Good to know.  And I'm less concerned about appearances than I am the actual value of the data I'm getting.

Comment: We're thinking of setting up piwik. @Phil are you using piwik on a "high-traffic" website? If so, would you be so nice and tell me the count of users/PIs you are handling and something about the instance sizing? Database Size/throughput and stuff?! Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is 8 years old now, so it's fair to say things have moved on a bit. I'd still comfortably recommend Piwik for a high traffic site: it's more than capable of the task. 
I've moved away from it for now as I concentrate more on .Net sites and lean more on tools that use SQL Server as the back end or Azure services (e.g. Application Insights).